# Issues with dropdown list onchange

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The running code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/rwdengmz/
I apologise as i cant explain clearly my problem but here goes.
eg: as i click on parent 1, it properly shows the value it exists in the child which is

- Child 1 from Parent 1
- Child 2 from Parent 1

This works fine however, the problem lies when i change parent option to example,Parent 2. It will then show yet again the proper child values

- Child 1 from Parent 2
- Child 2 from Parent 2

HOWEVER, before opening the dropdown it will show the previous child value and for this instance, it will show the child 1 from parent 1.

How do i make it that will just show purely the specific child values of the selected parent option?

```
<select id="parent">

    <option value="1">Parent 1</option>
    <option value="2">Parent 2</option>
    <option value="3">Parent 3</option>
</select>

<select id="child">
    <option data-parentid="1">Child 1 from Parent 1</option>
    <option data-parentid="1">Child 2 from Parent 1</option>
    <option data-parentid="2">Child 1 from Parent 2</option>
    <option data-parentid="2">Child 2 from Parent 2</option>
    <option data-parentid="3">Child 1 from Parent 3</option>
    <option data-parentid="3">Child 2 from Parent 3</option>
</select>

$("#parent").on("change", function()
{
    var id = $(this).val();

    $("#child option").each(function()
    {
        $(this).css("display", ($(this).data("parentid") == id ? "" : "none"));
    });
}).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is set the `attr` as `selected`. This should help you solve the issue where the previous value is still being displayed despite the `change` function called and the option being populated as desired.

```
$("#parent").on("change", function(){
    $('#child option').filter(function(){
        if($(this).data('parentid') == $('#parent').val()) {
            $(this).show().attr('selected','true');
        }
        else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });

});
```

Check out the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rwdengmz/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$("#parent").on("change", function()
{
    var id = $(this).val();
    $("#child").children('option').hide();
    $("select#child option[data-parentid="+id+"]").show().prop("selected", true);

}).trigger('change');
```